# Is a loop that is running a constant number of times considered Big - Oh(1)?

Tags: algorithm, loops, big-o

From a popular definition ,**a loop or recursion that runs a constant number of times is also considered as O(1)**.

For example the following loop is O(1)

```
// Here c is a constant   
for (int i = 1; i <= c; i++) {  
    // some O(1) expressions
}
```

**Time Complexity of a loop is considered as O(n) if the loop variables is incremented / decremented by a constant amount.**

For example following functions have O(n) time complexity.

```
// Here c is a positive integer constant   
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i += c) {  
    // some O(1) expressions
}
```

I got a little confused with the following example here lets take c = 5 and according to the O(1) definition the below code becomes - O(1)

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5 ; i++){
    cout<<"Hello<<endl";
}
```

### Function 1:

```
for(int i = 0; i < len(array); i+=2){
    if(key == array[i])
         cout<<"Element found";
}
```

### Function 2:

```
for(int i =0;i < len(array) ; i++){
    if(key == array[i])
        cout<<"Element found";
}
```

But when we compare the above 2 examples will they both become O(n) or first function is O(1) from definition.**What exaclty does a loop running constant number of times means?**

Comment: A single loop is a `O(1)`? No. And your first snippet it is `O(c)`

Comment: @FirstStep but `c` was a constant by definition

Comment: @FirstStep It could also be rewritten as `O(c*1)`. And since we don't care about constant factors in big-O notation, it is equivalent to `O(1)`

Comment: @FirstStep: if `c` is constant, the loop is `O(1)`.

Comment: @harold I know that when we do one step to reach the solution (output) then it is O(1) -> Like `MyStack.pop();`. Even if `c` is constant then the loop will need to iterate `c` times => `O(c)` no?

Comment: _the following loop is O(1)_ . Actually that loop is O(c). **You** have defined c to be an arbitary constant, so you can take it out.

Comment: It's all about how the number of operations performed varies with the properties (typically size) of the input.  If there is an upper bound on the number of operations the program performs that does not vary with the input size then it is O(1).

Comment: @FirstStep No, it is O(1).

Comment: @FirstStep can a loop becomes O(1) anytime.?

Comment: @FirstStep: if you iterate a constant amount of times, it's the same thing as doing the operation c times one after the other. `doit(); doit(); doit();` is the same as `for (auto i=0; i<3; ++i) doit();`, and the first one is obviously `O(1)`.

Comment: @SaiKiran, O(n/2) = O(n) because we don't care about coefficients.  We typically don't *write* coefficients (e.g. 1/2), either.

Comment: @SaiKiran: Simple, actually: `O(n*anything)`, where `anything` is some constant except 0, is the same as `O(n)`; we ignore all constant coefficients. `O(1)` means *constant* run time, ie. run time that is *completely* independent of the input size. This is the case in your first and third examples.

Comment: `From a popular definition`: please provide a source. (Doesn't hold in all generality.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that `len(array)` is the `b` we're talking about [*], both your functions are `O(n)`.

Function 2 will execute the `if` n times (once for each element of the array), making it obviously `O(n)`.

Function 1, on the other hand, will execute the `if` `n/2` times (once for every other element in the array), leading to a run time of `O(n*1/2)`, and since constant factors (`1/2` in this case) are usually omitted in O notation, you'll again end up with `O(n)`.

---

[*] For the sake of completeness, if your array were of a fixed size, ie. `len(array)` were a constant, than both functions would be `O(1)`.

Answer (score 1):

"Loop running a costant number of times" means the loop runs a number of times that is limited from above by a constant, i.e. a given **number that is indipendent from the input of your program**.
Both in function 1 and 2 (unless the lenghts of the arrays are fixed or you can prove they'll never be grater than a specific constant, indipendently of the input) the `if` will be execute a number of time that depends on the size of the input so the time complexity can't be O(1).
"Time Complexity of a loop is considered as O(n) if the loop variables is incremented / decremented by a constant amount" is a misleading definition

Comment: (`Loop running a` _constant_ `number of times`; _independent_,  _lengths_ (but, then, "Avoid trivial edits unless absolutely necessary"))